# Preventing SQL statements from getting truncated by MySQL's Workbench in `Performance Reports` section

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-workbench

Recently I was introduced to the new feature of MySQL: performance_schema, and it's awesome. Specially when it's joined with MySQL Workbench's `Performance Reports`. I find the `High Cost SQL Statements` section pretty useful and practical. There's only one downside to it, the SQL column which holds the executed SQL statement is truncated in long cases.

I believe it's truncated by Workbench and not the performance_schema but I've got no solid evidence to prove it. Does anyone know how to have the complete version of SQL?

Comment: I'm not sure in which table(s) the `Performance Reports`'s data is stored. I've looked the tables and there are a couple of them with `SQL_TEXT` field and it's of type `LONGTEXT` in all of them which is more than enough to hold any statement (4G). That's why I believe the statements are truncated by Workbench and not the MySQL server itself.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I managed to figure it out myself.

The information presented in MySQL Workbench's Dashboard are extracted using a series of views defined within `sys` database. The mentioned views are created based on the tables found in `performance_schema` database. The field responsible to hold SQL statements resides in `sys.x$statement_analysis` view which is taking it from `performance_schema.events_statements_summary_by_digest` table in turn. Even though this field is defined as `LONGTEXT` and can hold as many characters as 4G, but the SQL statements are truncated when they are inserted.

The maximum length of characters that will be inserted into `DIGEST_TEXT` is controlled by [**max_digest_length**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_digest_length) config. Its default value is set to **1024** and it can be increased as big as 1048576. But keep in mind that this config can be set on **MySQL version greater than 5.6.24** only!!

Comment: Great !  That makes perf reports useful !
I added thoses settings to my.ini (default value x 10) :
`max_digest_length=10240
performance_schema_max_sql_text_length=10240
performance_schema_max_digest_length=10240`

Comment: Note that as of 5.6.26 `performance_schema_max_digest_length` is now used instead of `max_digest_length`.  Great answer though when I set out  to figure out how to make these statement strings readable I did not expect to find an answer.  I didn't even really what what to google.  thx

Comment: If anyone is using MySQL Workbench to view the performance schema data like I am, then you also will need to go to `Edit>Preferences>SQL Execution` and set `Max. Field Value Length to Display` to the same max value otherwise statements will get truncated (showing beginning and end but with ellipses in the middle)